# Numeric value in the JSON property neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to unwind a json one of which nodes is numeric: 0.

```
{
  "0": {
    "return_at": "2020-05-20T15:00:00Z",
    "departure_at": "2020-03-24T16:15:00Z",
    "expires_at": "2020-02-29T03:10:12Z",
    "airline": "SU",
    "price": 22810,
    "flight_number": 6283
  }
}
```

Expectedly, when I `RETURN data.data.UUS.0`, Cypher throws the following error:
Invalid input '0': expected an identifier

I tried quoting, brackets, etc, but nothing helps. Could anyone give me a help with this, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself, guided by the syntax here at Stackoverflow. The answer is a pair of ``

data.data.UUS.`0`